# Example for Otrkit example in Xcode ios

Tags: objective-c, xcode, encryption, off-the-record-messaging

I wanna encryption using OTR, so i use the module from github

https://github.com/ChatSecure/OTRKit

i followed that read me file but i cant able to done the encryption,

is any one use the module "OTRKit" from github,
produce simple example for using OTRKit in xcode like encrypt a message "Hello" and Decryot that,(shows text in alert box is enough).

i hope will some one help me,

Thank u...

Comment: I have make a OTR Connection in XMPP but whenever I try to send an encoded message I can't... Did you find the solution? I can receive OTR messages but not able to encrypt them...